# Consulta con react router

Tags: reactjs, router

ando necesitando una mano con ReactRouter, quiero crear una navegación entre los proyectos, la idea es hacer click en “Proyecto 1” y que cargue en el rectángulo amarillo un componente pero a la hora de hacerlo, cambiar la ruta pero no aparece el componente. Dejo la maqueta de la sección y el código, cualquier idea me sirve!

[image: Maqueta]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te recomiendo leer [ask], el codigo no debe subirse en imagenes, recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola como va? Por lo que veo te esta faltando envolver todo en el BrowserRouter. Generalmente es renombrado a router.
Por lo que importalo primero de react-router-dom

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  NavLink
} from 'react-router-dom';
```

Luego envolve absolutamente todo tu componente dentro del Router, desde donde comienza el return (  y hasta donde termina ) .